# JComboBox ActionEvent performs with multiple comboboxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am performing actions for 2 combo boxes which involves in changing the background color of `JLabel`. Here is my code,

```
public class JavaApplication8 {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel signal1;
private JLabel signal2;
private JPanel s1Panel;
private JPanel s2Panel;
public JavaApplication8()
{
    try {
        prepareGUI();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication8.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
ClassNotFoundException
{
  JavaApplication8  swingControl = new JavaApplication8();      
  swingControl.showCombobox1();
}
public void prepareGUI() throws ClassNotFoundException
{
  mainFrame = new JFrame("Signal");
  mainFrame.setSize(300,200);
  mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  signal1 = new JLabel("Signal 1",JLabel.LEFT);        
  signal1.setSize(100,100);
  signal1.setOpaque(true);
  signal2 = new JLabel("Signal 2",JLabel.LEFT); 
  signal2.setSize(100,100);
  signal2.setOpaque(true);
  final DefaultComboBoxModel light = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
  light.addElement("Red");
  light.addElement("Green");
  final JComboBox s1Combo = new JComboBox(light);    
  s1Combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
      {
         if(s1Combo.getSelectedIndex() == 0) 
         {
             signal1.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }
         else
         {
             signal1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         }
      }

  });

  final JComboBox s2Combo1 = new JComboBox(light);    
  s2Combo1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
      {
         if(s2Combo1.getSelectedIndex() == 0) 
         {
             signal2.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }
         else
         {
             signal2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         }
      }

  });  
  s1Panel = new JPanel();
  s1Panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  JScrollPane ListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(s1Combo); 
  s1Panel.add(signal1);
  s1Panel.add(ListScrollPane);   
  s2Panel = new JPanel();
  s2Panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  JScrollPane List1ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(s2Combo1); 
  s2Panel.add(signal2);
  s2Panel.add(List1ScrollPane);
  mainFrame.add(s1Panel);
  mainFrame.add(s2Panel);
  String[] columnNames = {"Signal 1","Signal 2"};
  Object[][] data = {{"1","1"}};
  final JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
  JScrollPane tablepane = new JScrollPane(table);
  table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
  mainFrame.add(tablepane);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
 }    
}
```

When Executed, If I change the item from combo box 1, the 2nd combo box also performs the change. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Long ago since I last used Swing, but is it possible that the ActionListener gets tied to the shared DefaultComboBoxModel instead of the individual JComboBox objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a simple solution: don't have the `JComboBoxes` share the **same** model. If they share the same model, then changes to the selected item of one JComboBox causes a change in the shared model which changes the view of both JComboBoxes.

I wold use a method to create your combo-jlabel duo so as not to duplicate code. For instance:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class App8 extends JPanel {
   private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 2;
   private static final String SIGNAL = "Signal";
   private List<JComboBox<ComboColor>> comboList = new ArrayList<>();

   public App8() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      for (int i = 0; i < COMBO_COUNT; i++) {
         DefaultComboBoxModel<ComboColor> cModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(ComboColor.values());
         JComboBox<ComboColor> combo = new JComboBox<>(cModel);
         add(createComboLabelPanel((i + 1), combo));
         comboList.add(combo);
      }
   }

   private JPanel createComboLabelPanel(int index, final JComboBox<ComboColor> combo) {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      final JLabel label = new JLabel(SIGNAL + " " + index);
      label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      label.setOpaque(true);
      combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            ComboColor cColor = (ComboColor) combo.getSelectedItem();
            label.setBackground(cColor.getColor());
         }
      });

      panel.add(label);
      panel.add(combo);
      return panel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      App8 mainPanel = new App8();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("App8");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum ComboColor {
   RED("Red", Color.RED),
   GREEN("Green", Color.GREEN);

   private String text;
   private Color color;

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }
   private ComboColor(String text, Color color) {
      this.text = text;
      this.color = color;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Comment: I assumed the Model is a list item.

Comment: @Dhinesh: what's with your funky use of `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: It was suggested when I got Compilation Error. I tried to know the error, but I could not able to resolve it.

Comment: @Dhinesh: who suggested this? Your teacher??? It looks way off the map, and I strongly doubt that you should be using such a construct.

Comment: The hints/popups shown on error in netbeans suggested

Comment: @Dhinesh: Just get rid of it as it is not an exception that should be caught, and even if it should be you're catching it in the wrong way.

Comment: I am getting an error called `Driver Not Found` What do they mean by it?

Comment: In your example why GUI is not displaying?

Comment: @Dhinesh: the GUI displays fine for me. Are you sure that you're running the correct file?